# Apply compression to a mocked response

Tags: azure-api-management

Is it possible to apply compression (gzip) to a mocked response? Or is it limited to the outbound section? I tried to apply mocking in the outbound section but then I would need to "skip" the entire `<backend>` section as there is no backend yet..

This policy below works and I get a nice sample json back, but it's not compressed.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
    <base />
    <set-header name="Content-Encoding" exists-action="override">
        <value>gzip</value>
    </set-header>
    <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
</inbound>
<backend />
<outbound />
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it to work using `<return-response>` instead. So if anyone in the future stumbles upon this, here is the complete policy:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="Content-Encoding" exists-action="override">
            <value>gzip</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>{
             "success": true,
             "data": {
                "foo": [
                   {
                      "id": 1,
                      "bar": "xxx"
                   },
                   {
                      "id": 2,
                      "bar": "yyy"
                   },
                   {
                      "id": 3,
                      "bar": "zzz"
                   }
                ]
             }
 }</set-body>
    </return-response>
</inbound>
<backend />
<outbound />
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
</policies>
```